# What is the most optimal way of using media queries for responsiveness if I am using single custom created styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-modules

I have defined this component, and I am using it everywhere in my project to avoid repetitive style definitions:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const FlexibleContainer = styled.div`
  display: ${(props) => (props.display ? props.display : "flex")};
  justify-content: ${(props) => props.jc && props.jc};
  align-items: ${(props) => props.ai && props.ai};
  flex-direction: ${(props) => props.fd && props.fd};
  flex-wrap: ${(props) => props.wrap && props.wrap};
  gap: ${(props) => props.gap && props.gap};
  row-gap: ${(props) => props.rg && props.rg};
  column-gap: ${(props) => props.cg && props.cg};
  position: ${(props) => props.pos && props.pos};
  border-radius: ${(props) => props.br && props.br};
  padding: ${(props) => props.pddn && props.pddn};
  padding-top: ${(props) => props.pt && props.pt};
  padding-right: ${(props) => props.pr && props.pr};
  padding-bottom: ${(props) => props.pb && props.pb};
  padding-left: ${(props) => props.pl && props.pl};
  margin: ${(props) => props.mrgn && props.mrgn};
  margin-top: ${(props) => props.mt && props.mt};
  margin-right: ${(props) => props.mr && props.mr};
  margin-bottom: ${(props) => props.mb && props.mb};
  margin-left: ${(props) => props.ml && props.ml};
  background-color: ${(props) => props.bg && props.bg};
  height: ${(props) => props.h && props.h};
  width: ${(props) => props.w && props.w};
  max-width: ${(props) => props.maxW && props.maxW};
  max-height: ${(props) => props.maxH && props.maxH};
  min-width: ${(props) => props.minW && props.minW};
  min-height: ${(props) => props.minH && props.minH};
`
const Container = (props) => {
  return <FlexibleContainer {...props}>{props.children}</FlexibleContainer>;
};
export default Container;
```

And this is the way I use it:

```
return (
    <Container gap="30px" ai="start">
      <LeftBar
        handler={handleSetSuggestionsIDs}
        suggestions={props.suggestions}
      />
      <Container gap="24px" fd="column" w="100%" minW="0px">
        <TopBar
          suggestions={suggestionIDs.map((id) =>
            props.suggestions.find((suggestion) => suggestion.id === id)
          )}
          handler={handleSetSuggestionsIDs}
        />
        {suggestionIDs.length ? (
          <Suggestions
            suggestions={suggestionIDs.map((id) =>
              props.suggestions.find((suggestion) => suggestion.id === id)
            )}
            handler={props.handler}
          />
        ) : (
          <NoFeedBackScreen />
        )}
      </Container>
    </Container>
  );`
```

Now I have to make it responsive for mobile and tablet screen sizes, and I cannot think of any method that would not make the JSX ugly. I have thought of using CSS modules with media queries, but if I do that now and keep creating new styles with class names the whole point of using styled components does not make sense anymore. On the other hand, if I create different props for mobile and tablet, or add ternary comparisons to each occurrence of Container, this would again lead to messy JSX filled with styles.

Comment: I think you've painted yourself into a corner here. All of those CSS rules are going to be injected as inline HTML, making it impossible to use media queries.

Is there a reason not to just use classnames and external CSS here? It would be a lot less repetitive (and possibly more performant) than passing every single css rule as a prop to these components

Comment: You are right, looks like I have overcomplicated it